# Recommended method to retrieve user personal site URL

Tags: 2013, user-profile

I use following method to retrieve URL of personal site:

```
    private string GetPersonalSite(SPSite site)
    {
        var curUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
        ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
        UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(context);
        UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(curUser.LoginName);
        return profile.PersonalUrl.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

However, `ServerContext` class is deprecated.

> ServerContext is obsolete. Use SPServiceContext.

Could you explain me, how to retrieve personal site from `SPServiceContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private string GetPersonalSite(SPSite site)
{
    var curUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site); 
    UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(context);
    UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(curUser.LoginName);
    return profile.PersonalUrl.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

that should work! same consept just changed ServerContext to SPServiceContext ;)

both have the same spsite context retrival!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee546948.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms499329.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use `SPServiceContenxt`

```
 SPServiceContext serverContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(mySite);    
 //Create an instance of the User Profile Manager
 UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
```

Comment: I only see one down-vote and three upvotes.

Comment: But nobody posted a feedback on why I am being down-voted?

Comment: It's how the system works. You are allowed to anonymously down-vote posts, even if I feel it's wrong. We (mods) can't see who voted on which post.